# Print command returns null dataframe

Tags: dataframe, printing, output, row, vectorization

I have three Excel tables that I want to concatenate some columns of them.

1 - Coilid - 1084 rows
2 - Retifica5 - 1456 rows
3 - Retifica4 - 1456 rows

I vectorized them, and now the purpose is take data content of coilid, verify if the item is between start date and end date in retifica5 - if it's yes, so print together coilname (in coil id), stand (in retifica5) and retifica (in retifica5). On another part of the running, do the same for retifica4.

The final part is not returning any answer - it's returning:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

The length of cc is 0. I'm not understanding why its not running.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load dataframes
retifica5 = pd.read_excel('C:\Doideira.xlsx', sheet_name='Plan1')
retifica4 = pd.read_excel('C:\Doideira.xlsx', sheet_name='Plan2')
coilid = pd.read_excel('C:\Arquivoparamim.xlsx', sheet_name='Planilha2')

# Sort dataframes by dates
retifica5 = retifica5.sort_values(by=['Data Retífica'], ascending=True)
retifica4 = retifica4.sort_values(by=['Data Retífica'], ascending=True)
coilid = coilid.sort_values(by=['DT_START'], ascending=True)

# Perform the comparison using vectorized operations
coildate = coilid['DT_START']
coil = coilid['CD_COIL']
retidata5 = retifica5['Data Entrada']
retidatas5 = retifica5['Data Saída']
retidata4 = retifica4['Data Entrada']
retidatas4 = retifica4['Data Saída']
reti5 = retifica5['Ret.']
reti4 = retifica4['Ret.']


coildate_filtered = coildate.reset_index(drop=True)
coil_filtered = coil.reset_index(drop=True)
retidata5_filtered = retidata5.reset_index(drop=True)
retidatas5_filtered = retidatas5.reset_index(drop=True)
retidata4_filtered = retidata4.reset_index(drop=True)
retidatas4_filtered = retidatas4.reset_index(drop=True)
reti5_filtered = reti5.reset_index(drop=True)
reti4_filtered = reti4.reset_index(drop=True)

cc=pd.DataFrame()
#Começando a unir lógicas
x=0
y=0
for x in range (coilname_filtered.shape[0]):
    for y in range  (retidata4_filtered.shape[0]):
        if (coildate_filtered[x]>retidata5_filtered[y])and(coildate_filtered[x]<retidatas5_filtered[y]):
            cc=[coilname_filtered[x],reti5_filtered[y]]
        
        break
        
print(cc)
```

My vectors follows bellow. They are all in pd.dataframe.

```
coilname_filtered

0       A623040100_1
1       A624140300_1
2       A624140400_1
3       A624140500_1
4       A624140600_1
            ...     
1079    C498350300_1
1080    C498350400_1
1081    C498350500_1
1082    C498350600_1
1083    C498350800_1
Name: CD_COIL, Length: 1084, dtype: object 


Coildata_filtered

0       44198.726921
1       44200.816458
2       44200.820231
3       44200.825486
4       44200.847986
            ...     
1079    44712.710289
1080    44712.717431
1081    44712.722674
1082    44712.976574
1083    44712.993438
Name: DT_START, Length: 1084, dtype: float64

retidata5_filtered
 0       44455.912500
1       44441.646528
2       44331.458333
3       44331.824306
4       44329.004167
            ...     
1503    45024.504861
1504    45025.026389
1505    45025.168750
1506    45024.771528
1507    45026.004167
Name: Data Entrada, Length: 1508, dtype: float64 

retidatas5_filtered
0       44455.988194
1       44236.783333
2       44331.465278
3       44331.965278
4       44329.038889
            ...     
1503    45024.771528
1504    45025.168750
1505    45026.004167
1506    45025.026389
1507    45026.206250
Name: Data Saída, Length: 1508, dtype: float64

Reti5_filtered

Name: Data Saída, Length: 1508, dtype: float64 0       18
1       18
2       18
3       18
4       18
        ..
1503    19
1504    19
1505    19
1506    18
1507    18
Name: Ret., Length: 1508, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Are the three *spreadsheets/tables/dataframes* aligned ? They have the same number of rows ? Can you share a reproducible example and the exact matching expected output ?

Comment: they have no same numbers of rows - Retifica5 has no the same than coilid

Comment: but one retifica produce many coilid.

Comment: OK but I think you need to share a minimal reproducible example _as text_ (a few rows/cols) of your three dataframes and show the expected output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added the vectors above